# nuxt3 website http://sdmfe.site:24678/_nuxt/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a nuxt3 website and I am getting the following error

http://sdmfe.site:24678/_nuxt/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

my nuxt.config.ts is as follows:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
modules: [
    "@vueuse/nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    "@formkit/nuxt",
    [
        "@pinia/nuxt",
        {
            autoImports: ["defineStore", "acceptHMRUpdate"],
        },
    ],
],
buildModules: [
    'nuxt-vite'
],
vite: {
    server: {
        hmr: {
            protocol: "ws",
            host: "0.0.0.0",
        },
    },
    build: true
},
css: ["@/assets/main.css"],
tailwindcss: {
    config: {
        content: ["./node_modules/laravel-vue-pagination/**/*.vue"],
    },
},
runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
        appURL: "http://sdm.site:8000",
    },
},
ssr: false,
});
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I fix it